# Как добавить текстовый контент из массива строк в новый элемент по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется массив строк, задача использовать эти названия как текстовый контент динамически создающегося элемента - `<li><a> text </a></li>` - по нажатию кнопки(button) которая добавляет этот элемент на страницу с НОВЫМ текстовым контентом взятым из массива строк. [image: Первое нажатие кнопки и добавлен новый элемент] [image: При последующих нажатиях происходит повтор текстового контента в элементе] После повторного нажатия элемент добавляется, но текстовый контент не меняется(который должен был взят из массива строк). Как решить такую проблему? Помогите пожалуйста.
Код:

```
const addNameElem = ['PHP', 'Go', 'Phyton', 'MySQL', 'Angular'];

const addBtn = document.querySelector('.js-add-btn');
let labelContentElem = addNameElem[Math.floor(Math.random() * addNameElem.length)];


addBtn.addEventListener('click', onAddBtnClick);

function onAddBtnClick() {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    const tagLink = document.createElement('a');

    tagLink.classList.add('btn');
    tagLink.textContent = `${labelContentElem}`;
    item.appendChild(tagLink);

    nav.appendChild(item);
    [...new Set(labelContentElem)];
    // labelContentElem += 1;
}
```

Comment: Да, без кода точно решить не получится, т.к. телепаты тут не сидят :)

Comment: Вот эту строку `let labelContentElem = addNameElem[Math.floor(Math.random() * addNameElem.length)];` поместите в функцию `onAddBtnClick`. Должно помочь

Comment: И, так как рандом не идеален, то после того, как добавили элемент, удаляйте соответствующую строку из массива строк

Comment: Перенос, того куска кода который вы указали во внутрь функции onAddBtnClick, действительно помог решить задачу с изменением текстового контентна внутри элемента. Огромное вам спасибо)

А, каким лучше способом удалять строку из массива?

Comment: @SergGorelikov, лучше использовать метод `splice(start, end)` у массивов. `start` - начать удалять элементы с позиции `start`; `end` - сколько удалить. К примеру: `addNameElem.splice(1, 1);` удалит элемент "Go"

Comment: С вашего позволения, я вынесу комментарий в ответ. Так будет понятнее, что вопрос имеет какое-то решение

Comment: Ну а определить, позицию, с которой вам предстоит удалить элемент, не является проблемой. Просто запоминайте в переменную результат рандома `let positionElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * addNameElem.length);`. То есть получится что-то типа такого:  `addNameElem.splice(positionElement, 1);`. И используйте её же в `let labelContentElem = addNameElem[positionElement];`

P.S. Вроде бы ничего не напутал, но направление вот точно рабочее))

Comment: @Pr0gramm1st, да действительно отлично получилось как вы написали в комментарии выше)))
Только небольшие корректировки с моей стороны и все стало на свои места, и как вы сказали: P.S. Вроде бы ничего не напутал, но направление вот точно рабочее))

Вот так в две строки кода и работает без сбоев:
        **let positionElem = Math.floor(Math.random() * addNameElem.length);**
 **let labelContentElem = addNameElem.splice(positionElem, 1);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эту строку `let labelContentElem = addNameElem[Math.floor(Math.random() * addNameElem.length)];` поместите в функцию `onAddBtnClick`. Должно помочь